# C++ Reading an unknown number of integers to cin and outputting the sum

Tags: c++, visual-studio, loops, cin

I am brand new to c++ and I am trying to write my own version of a program that prints the sum of an unknown number of integers read from cin.

The only preprocessor directive that I have covered is `#include <iostream>`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int numbers;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> i;
        sum += i;
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
cl /EHsc /W4 sum_of_set_of_integers.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.14.26433 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

sum_of_set_of_integers.cpp
a:\c++ tutorial\michael_dawson\sum_of_set_of_integers.cpp(8) : warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'numbers' used
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.14.26433.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:sum_of_set_of_integers.exe
sum_of_set_of_integers.obj

A:\C++ Tutorial\Michael_Dawson>sum_of_set_of_integers
1
1
1
1
1
```

I am unable to break out of the loop.It would be of great help if youcould advice..

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a number that means end?

Comment: You forgot to initialize `numbers` with a reasonable value: `int numbers;`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++)` What do you expect the value of `numbers` to be at this point? You never read it, nor do you set it to anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that you don't know in advance how many integers are going to come in, so you can't use that `for` loop -- there's no sensible value for `numbers`.

Instead, keep reading values until the end of the input:

```
while (std::cin >> i)
    sum += i;
```

When the attempted read eventually fails, the `while` loop will exit.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: use CTRL + Z (end of line)

Answer (score 0):

Complier is suggesting, please read carefully.

```
a:\c++ tutorial\michael_dawson\sum_of_set_of_integers.cpp(8) : warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'numbers' used
```

**Also please try to follow 0-errors and 0-warnings principle.**

Using a while loop keep reading and adding integers until end of input. Updated code should look like this:

```
int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (std::cin >> i)
        sum += i;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i'd rather be careful with telling a beginner that code "should" look like something, especially when it has `std::cin` that actually should come with error checking and such, just saying...

Comment: Changing the purpose/behaviour of the code isn't an answer imho

Comment: @Korni - I don't understand how I am changing the behaviour/purpose ? Please suggest

Comment: @Rizwan OP asked: > "[...] prints the sum of an unknown number of integers read from cin". In your version the number is set in the beginning

Comment: @Korni - Absolutely correct. I missed that point. Thanks for pointing. Updated the answer.